Is there any connection between the reparameterization of a geodesic equation and the choice of connection?
We have a freedom in the choice of the connection in the sense like adding a tensor to an existing connection is also valid connection and when using non-affine parameterization of a geodesic we have an extra force like term. So are the two connected in anyway?
PS: I do know it as a fact that the connection is a geometric property and reparameterization should not effect the connection. This question spontaneously propped up when looking for an intuitive interpretation for the force like terms appearing when using non-affine parameterizations.

What do you mean by "reparametrization should not affect the connection"? A geodesic must have constant speed, so a parametrized curve with non-constant speed corresponds to a change in the metric, hence a change in connection.

@TedShifrin What I mean to say is that given a connection, which can vary from one point to another on the Manifold, reparameterization of the geodesic should not effect the connection and the way it varies. Is this reasoning correct? PS: Info to indicate my current level of understanding: I have just started my course in General Relativity.
